# OpenGL (ES) -- glBindBuffer throws IllegalArgumentException: remaining < size()

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

I've made a buffer of vertices that correctly draw when using glDrawArrays, however they fail to load into a VBO. Here's the code:

```
FloatBuffer circleBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(numVertices * 3 *
  4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++) {
  circleBuffer.put((float) (Math.cos(theta)));
  circleBuffer.put((float) (Math.sin(theta)));
  circleBuffer.put(1);
  theta += 2 * Math.PI / (numVertices);
}

int[] buffer = new int[1];
int circleIndex=0;  
gl11.glGenBuffers(1, buffer,0);
circleIndex = buffer[0];
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, circleIndex);
gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, circleBuffer.capacity() * 4,
  circleBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

I outputed the capacity of the buffer and it is 105, and the remaining is 0. I also tried reassigning the FloatBuffer as a Buffer. What's wrong here? Thanks!

---

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7127): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: remaining() < size
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7127): at com.google.android.gles_jni.GLImpl.glBufferData(Native Method)
```

EDIT -- Solution

```
buffer.flip();
```

Comment: Are you sure that glBindBuffer is throwing an exception? GL functions don't throw exceptions, it could be that another non-GL method is throwing the exception.

Comment: I think from flip's implementation you were only missing .position(0)

Answer (score 0):

A Java exception which should be deliberately thrown by methods that don't like their parameters. It extends RuntimeException, which means it does not need to be caught.
The singular name notwithstanding, can represent unsatisfied constraint between more parameters. The more you use and check the parameters, the more you move towards exception in the method invocation proper.
In many cases, code that is throwing NullPointerException should be argument-checking and throwing this, with a decent explanitory message.

Comment: @Oded Android apps are developed in Java (in most cases), this case is one of them.